# USB Modem Stopped Connecting

Tags: usb-modem

i had my USB Modem ZTE working fine on Ubuntu, untill yesterday it won't connect anymore, yet it's detected as a modem in the connection manager but it won't connect, i tried it in Windows to make sure n it was working fine, and i have no idea how to troubleshoot the USB Modem!!!
Thanks in advance.!

[This's what i get trying to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCrs6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ran

```
sudo apt-get install udev-discover
```

And restarted the system.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I can't do this coz i don't have internet access, i don't think this command will run probably!!!!!

Comment: I've been having this problem for two days now.  Can I run this command on Ubuntu 17.10 or will it cause problems?  Sorry, I'm still very new with Ubuntu and very ignorant :-(